# How to call multiple APIs returning Observable<Response> and aggregate their responses to a single Object

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have to create an aggregated POJO named say **Product.java**, by calling multiple sources/Rest APIs (#sources can be any number) and parse their individual responses (Observable<Response>) to populate relevant fields in Product.java

Observable.zip() kinda suits my requirement, but it takes a fixed no. of args, whereas in my case #sources (args) can be any configurable number.

Is there a generic/ cleaner way to do this?

```
List<Source> sources = //Some configuration, where sources.size() 
// Call all source REST APIs in parallel where each returns an Observable<Response>
// Parse each Observable<Response> & populate the relevant fields in a shared Product.java Object. (No two responses will try to populate the same field in Product)
```

Comment: You can send to Observable.zip() list of your observables. Not a fixed amount of arguments

Comment: https://gist.github.com/torgeir/bdfffbdfdc8ed98056b8

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important, just .merge() and .scan(); if it is important, use .concat() instead of .merge()

```java
final Observable<MyContainer> myContainer = Observable
  .merge(sources)
  .scan(new MyContainer(), (myContainer, newProduct) -> {
     // add newProduct to myContainer
     return myContainer;
  })
```